# Firefox doesn't support a long path

Tags: html, firefox

Firefox does not support a long path.
But in IE code is run smoothly.

```
<img src="C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Images/Skin_Tone/light.JPG" width= "50" height="30"/>
```

This is the path.
If I use a short path then it work in firefox but if I use above path then it didn't show an image.

But it shows an image in IE.

Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with PHP

Comment: but can you give solution for running this code with long path in firefox

Comment: see Hamid's answer but you should consider using relative urls

Comment: Why are you using a local file path instead of a url?  You need to put in the web address of the image, not the path that will only work on your computer.

Comment: Could it be the space in the file name (Program Files)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use relative addressing rather than absolute addressing.

Asuming you have no other choice, use this `file:///` in front of the addresses.

```
<img src="file:///C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Images/Skin_Tone/light.JPG" width= "50" height="30"/>
```

Comment: after completing my project i will upload this website to webhost,that time how i give path.

Comment: @Pratikg88 have a look at this article http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 3):

Full paths (that's what you are calling a long path) should include a protocol: add `file:///` to the beginning of the path

Comment: Or a "feature". No seriously, it was probably intentional (and makes sense from a Microsoft point of view), so calling it a bug is not the full truth. Still, it can be confusing, is non-standard and really shouldn't be that way.

Answer (score 2):

**Referencing an image from a local file**

You need to upload your picture from a publically available source (probably the web!)  It looks like you have uploaded it, but you probably should be referencing it relatively, for example something like:

```
<img src="Images/Skin_Tone/light.JPG" width= "50" height="30"/>
```

(Modify path as necessary)

**Getting mixed up with client/server side**

PHP has nothing to do with firefox or internet explorer or any other browser.  It is server side, and you are referncing a client side problem.

Comment: At times using a local file is what you want. Not too often, but it does happen. The comment about php is a good one.